# Doesn't recognize imports of interface in the same namespace? seems like MainViewModel is isolated from other classes in the namespace C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, viewmodel

I am making a reversi game in C# with visual studio. I have a ViewModel namespace with a MainViewModel.cs class, where i create an interface Screen. When I want to use this interface in other classes like WelcomeViewModel.cs, which is in the same namespace, it doesn't recognize Screen. Below some sample of my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Model.Reversi;
using View;

namespace ViewModel
{
    class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Screen screen;

        public event Action ExitApp;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Screen Screen
        {
            get { return this.screen; }
            set { this.screen = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Screen))); }
        }
        internal void Exit()
        {
            ExitApp?.Invoke();

        }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.Screen = new WelcomeViewModel(this);

        }
    }
    public abstract class Screen
    {
        protected readonly MainViewModel mainModel;

        protected Screen(MainViewModel mainModel)
        {
            this.mainModel = mainModel;
        }

        protected void Switch(Screen screen)
        {
            this.mainModel.Screen = screen;
        }
    }

    public class ScreenWelcome : Screen
    {
        public ScreenWelcome(MainViewModel navigator) : base(navigator)
        {
            GoToGame = new EasyCommand(() => Switch(new ScreenGame(navigator)));
        }

        public ICommand GoToGame { get; }
    }

    public class ScreenGame : Screen
    {
        public ScreenGame(MainViewModel navigator) : base(navigator)
        {
            GoToWelcome = new EasyCommand(() => Switch(new ScreenWelcome(navigator)));
        }

        public ICommand GoToWelcome { get; }
    }
}
```

`WelcomeViewModel` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ViewModel.Screen;
using Model.Reversi;

namespace ViewModel
{
    class WelcomeViewModel: Screen
    {
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public int Width
        {
            get { return width; }
            set {
                if (ReversiBoard.IsValidWidth(value))
                    this.width = value;
            }
        }

        public int Height
        {
            get { return height; }
            set
            {
                if (ReversiBoard.IsValidHeight(value))
                    this.height = value;
            }
        }
        public WelcomeViewModel(MainViewModel mainModel) : base(mainModel)
        {
            this.Width = 9;
            this.Height = 9;

            this.Options = new PlayerOptionsViewModel();

            Start = new EasyCommand(() =>
            {
                Switch(new GameViewModel(this.mainModel, Options, Width, Height));
            });
        }
        public PlayerOptionsViewModel Options { get; set; }
        public ICommand Start { get; }
    }
}
```

the : Screen stays white so it means it doesn't recognize the Screen class. How is this possible?

Anyone has a solution? [enter image description here][1]

[image]

Comment: You should not rely on colors but on compiler messages. Are you getting compilation errors? What do they say?

Comment: You're exposing an internal class in a protected field of your public `Screen` class. I doubt this compiles

Comment: By moving it to a whole new project it worked

Comment: but you guys know how ican fix the inconsistent accesibility error?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely getting

> Error  CS0051  Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'MainViewModel' is less accessible than method 'ScreenWelcome.ScreenWelcome(MainViewModel)'

In the public class `ScreenWelcome` you have the constructor `public ScreenWelcome(MainViewModel navigator)`. This constructor exposes `MainViewModel` in its public interface, therefore class `MainViewModel` must be public as well. Make it public

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
}
```